# DateTime de donde coge el formato, depende del idioma?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

Estoy trabajando con windows server con su version en ingles, pero en el sistema cliente me coge el formato de fecha en "M/d/yyyy".

Ya cambie el idioma y el formato de fecha del servidor pero no se cambia.

Alguna idea?

Comment: "La resolución de esta propiedad depende del temporizador del sistema no de la configuración de idioma." - Comentario de [Adrián Blanco](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/39618/adri%C3%A1n-blanco)

Comment: Deberías poner un ejemplo detallado del problema que tienes, para que puedas recibir una ayuda adecuada (incluyendo algún trozo de código).

Comment: `DateTime.Now` no tiene ningun formato. Es una fecha almacenada como un entero. El formato se le da cuando es convertido a `string`. Si amplias tu pregunta con algo de codigo, podremos ayudarte mas

Comment: ¿Te refieres al formato que toma el *codebehind* en C# o el que toma SQL Server?

Comment: En el título de la pregunta haces referencia a `DateTime.Now`, pero en el texto detallas que cambiaste el idioma y formato en el servidor. No queda claro cuál es el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te refieres a que quieres establecer el texto a partir de un objeto `DateTime` sin tener que escribir un montón de código propio, quizás esto es lo que buscas:

```
using System.Globalization;
///
DateTimeFormatInfo MxFormat = new CultureInfo("es-MX", false).DateTimeFormat;
string Fecha = DateTime.Now.ToString(MxFormat.LongDatePattern);
```

---

**EDIT**

De acuerdo a lo que mencionas, quieres convertir una `String` a un `DateTime`. Para hacerlo respetando el formato en español `dd/mm/aaaa` debes hacerlo así:

```
DateTime dt; // A esta variable asignarás el valor.
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(MiString,             //Primero la variable
                           "dd/MM/yyyy",         //El formato esperado
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, //Información de cultura
                           DateTimeStyles.None,  //Formato de análisis
                           out dt))              //Variable a la que se asignará el valor
{
    // la fecha es válida
} 
else 
{
    // la fecha no es válida
}
```

Comment: Perdón amigos, lo que pasa que soy nuevo en esto. El problema es que tengo un string "25/04/2017", y quiero convertirlo a Fecha. Cuando hago Convert.ToDateTime("25/04/2017"); en un sistema windows en su versión en ingles, muestra un error de formato no válido; pero en un sistema windows en español, si me realiza la conversión

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta, por favor revisa si te funciona.